# How to fix "Xcode quit unexpectedly while using the libclang.dylib plug-in."?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5, clang, libclang

I have this every time in a short while after I start xCode (`5.1.1`).

Removed user data, turned off source control (as some posts suggested), no effect, still crashes (while showing Indexing... that never finishes). **Even reinstalled** xCode, without any effect, still says the same.

**Did anybody fixed such an xCode?**

[image]

Here's the crashing thread:

```
 Thread 7 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: IDEIndex PCH Creation Lock
    0   libclang.dylib                  0x00000001080c60d9 void llvm::BitstreamWriter::EmitRecordWithAbbrevImpl<unsigned long long>(unsigned int, llvm::SmallVectorImpl<unsigned long long>&, llvm::StringRef) + 809
    1   libclang.dylib                  0x00000001080c5867 void llvm::BitstreamWriter::EmitRecord<unsigned long long>(unsigned int, llvm::SmallVectorImpl<unsigned long long>&, unsigned int) + 71
    2   libclang.dylib                  0x00000001081e9f25 clang::ASTWriter::WriteASTCore(clang::Sema&, llvm::StringRef, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, clang::Module*) + 35045
    3   libclang.dylib                  0x00000001081e160e clang::ASTWriter::WriteAST(clang::Sema&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, clang::Module*, llvm::StringRef, bool) + 6830
    4   libclang.dylib                  0x00000001080719a3 clang::ASTUnit::Save(llvm::StringRef) + 691
    5   libclang.dylib                  0x0000000107fe974f clang_saveTranslationUnit + 543
    6   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x0000000106ac63af -[IDEIndexClangTranslationUnit cxTranslationUnit] + 331
    7   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x0000000106c2c11a +[IDEIndexClangDataSource translationUnitForPCHFile:arguments:session:create:] + 259
    8   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x0000000106cf5552 __90-[IDEIndex createPCHFile:arguments:hashCriteria:target:session:willIndex:translationUnit:]_block_invoke + 1739
    9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff957012ad _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff95702166 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 39
    11  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x0000000105fce5cf -[DVTDispatchLock performLockedBlock:] + 95
    12  com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x0000000106cf4932 -[IDEIndex createPCHFile:arguments:hashCriteria:target:session:willIndex:translationUnit:] + 919
    13  com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x0000000106ac4985 -[IDEIndexClangDataSource generateDataForJob:] + 1274
    14  com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x0000000106ac42fb -[IDEIndexDataSource processJob:] + 147
    15  com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x0000000106ac3e33 +[IDEIndexingEngine runFileJob:] + 732
    16  com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x0000000106ac3550 -[IDEIndexingJob run] + 161
    17  com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x0000000106c3233c __40-[IDEIndexingJobScheduler _scheduleJobs]_block_invoke + 33
    18  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff957041d7 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    19  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff957012ad _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    20  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff9570309e _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 326
    21  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff95704193 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 40
    22  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ead7ef8 _pthread_wqthread + 314
    23  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8eadafb9 start_wqthread + 13
```

Or you may find the full crash report at https://gist.github.com/eppz/10669132

Comment: `IDEIndex PCH Creation Lock` > looks like Xcode tries to index a project when crashing. When "Reopening", does Xcode propose not to open previous windows? Maybe try to move/delete Xcode preferences/metadatas: `~/Library/Developer/Xcode`, `~/Library/Application Support/Xcode`... Or try login with a different user account? (with no such files)

Comment: Thanks, gonna try each.

Comment: Seems project specific, as I can work fine with other projects. Is there anything I can reset at the project level (beside ~/Library/Developer/Xcode files)?

Comment: You can try to edit by hand `YouProject.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` but that is `JSON` or `XML` and might be difficult to fix. Recreating your project from scratch might be the easiest/quickest solution...

Comment: Btw Xcode crash while creating `PCH` which stands for PreCompiled Headers. So maybe the crash is induced by your source, and not project file. Do you have a `something.pch` file? If so, maybe try to comment its content.

Comment: I found it by merge changes one-by-one, it is 2 tiny class, that made the indexing wreck.

Comment: Glad you fixed it :) Did I help? Should I post an answer to claim my reward?

Comment: I can see nothing special, I've just started to create them.

Comment: If you answer something like: "Grab the changes since xCode worked last time, then add changes again one-by-one". :D

Comment: Belive or not, as soon as I added the two class, xCode crashed immediately. Facin' weird anyway.

Comment: Got it! I included a `.m` file in an interface file!!!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50683/discussion-between-vincent-g-and-geri)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**There was a `.m` file in an `#import` statement!**

It was caused by one single line of code! Can't belive it. Stole 4 hours of figuring out. Oh, it was combined by a `@class` statement.

It shows up as an error, but xCode / Clang is crashing faster than you can even build. :D

The deadly pattern:

**One.h**

```
#import "Two.m" // Not easy to spot actually.

@interface One : NSObject
@end
```

**Two.h**

```
@class One;
@interface Two : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, weak) One *one;
@end
```

I can't reproduce it unless with the project I mentioned with over 200 classes. That must be some kind of race-condition.

Comment: This is obviously a bug in llvm clang, maybe you should report it to them ;) http://clang.llvm.org

Comment: You, my dear friend, just save me several hours of pain and frustration... If you ever find yourself in Tokyo, let me know, I'll buy you a drink.

Comment: I believe invitations to India are also in order. :)

Answer (score 4):

If you have an @Implementation in any Objective-C header file it seems to be enough to cause it to fail as well.

Comment: Yap, seems it is technically the same.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had an import to an umbrella header file inside of the umbrella header file itself.

For example:

Inside of MyFramework.h, I had:

```
#import <MyFramework/MyFramework.h>
```

The indexer hates this!

Answer (score 1):

From logs: `IDEIndex PCH Creation Lock` > looks like Xcode tries to index a project when crashing.

So try to figure what can cause this in your project or source code, maybe compare your latest working version with current one.